# Error in bootloader: Help in assembly

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bootloader

I am trying to create a simple operating system, yet when I compile the bootloader, I get the error:

```
error: binary output format does not support external references
```

I know what this error means, but is it possible to make external references when compiling to  binary format?  Here is my complete code:

```
;Bootloader.s
[BITS 16]     
[ORG 0x7C00]
global loader
extern kmain

loader:
call kmain
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

And my kernel:

```
/*kernel.c*/
void kmain()
{
    unsigned char *vidmem = (unsigned char *) 0xb8000;
    int i
    for(i=1;i<=11;i+=2)
    {
        vidmem[i]=0x07;
    }
    vidmem[0]='H';
    vidmem[2]='e';
    vidmem[4],vidmem[6]='l';
    vidmem[8]='o';
    videmem[10]='!';
}
```

How I compiled:

```
nasm -o '/home/myusername/Cubed OS/Bootloader.o' '/home/myusername/Cubed OS/Bootloader.s'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only have external references in object file formats that are linkable. A bare binary is not, so you can't do that directly.

(And you need to set up a stack before you can call a C function AFAIK.)

I see three ways of going about this:

- Use a bootloader that has Multiboot, and write your kernel as an ELF image. See the OSDev [Bare bones](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones) for an example of that.
- Write the whole thing in assembly. See for example [How to write a simple operating system](http://mikeos.berlios.de/write-your-own-os.html).
- Write it all in `C` and use linker tricks to get things aligned where they need to be. An example of this with the GCC toolchain can be found here: [Real mode in C with gcc : writing a bootloader](http://dc0d32.blogspot.com/2010/06/real-mode-in-c-with-gcc-writing.html)

Comment: What format can you have external references and use the  "ORG" directive?